# Is there any way to provide feedback to proposers and reviewers of editors?

Tags: support, editing

A user kindly proposed this edit, and two other users approved it:

https://superuser.com/revisions/308130/5

Despite the facts that it contains erroneous formatting (it puts the code backticks around thw non-code word "is" in the second paragraph), and that it replaces the original broken link at the bottom with another equally broken link.

I've edited again to correct the mistakes. Is there any way to let the editor and reviewers know about that, so they can keep a closer eye on those kinds of errors next time?

Comment: It being your own answer , it is possible that you could RollBack the edit easier?

Comment: Ugh. Those formatting changes are just unnecessary. You can @ping past editors in a comment on the post, but the only way to contact reviewers would be to get a mod in chat to superping them, if you can find a willing mod.

Comment: Ah, i assumed the formatting changes were to conform with SU norms. Do we have conventions about command names should be formatted in body text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no there is no way to contact directly the reviewers or proposers of an edit.  However there are a few things you can do to try and draw their attention:

1. You can use the 'ping' (`@<insert name>`) in the comments of a question/answer that you feel is necessary to bring to attention.  I would only use this for minor to moderate issues that are ok to bring up on the question/answer, but won't distract from the overall direction that post is going.
2. You can do exactly what you did here.  Use the Meta to post your concern about a specific edit.  Most reviewers will also visit the Meta and therefore see this concern you have.
3. If the edit if flagrantly bad, or there appears to be an edit war, flag the question for moderator intervention.  They can directly contact the parties involved and take the necessary actions.